# Move Mailbox Database role

Tags: exchange-2010

The question is regarding Exchange 2010.
I have the following situation: one domain, two servers (t-ex1, site1; t-ex2, site2).

The t-ex1 server is configured with the following roles:
- Mailbox Database
- Hub transport
- CAS server

I need to move Mailbox Database role from t-ex1 to t-ex2. Apparently, I'll need to move Hub transport role to the new server too.
After migration, t-ex1 should only have CAS server role.
What is the best way to perform this operation? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install the Hub Transport and Mailbox roles to the new server.
- Reconfigure your inbound mail flow to go to the new server instead of the old one.
- Reconfigure your outbound mail flow (send connectors) to go through the new server instead of the old one.
- Move all mailboxes to the new server.
- Move all public folder replicas to the new server (if you are using PFs).
- Configure the new server to handle OAB generation.
- Remove the Mailbox and Hub Transport roles from the old server.

Beware: if the two servers are in two different Active Directory sites, the CAS role remaining on the first site will be totally useless (it will only be able to proxy requests to a CAS server in the other site, which you will still need for Exchange to work). You can't have a single CAS server in a site and a single Hub/Mailbox server in another site.

Comment: Massimo, thanks! One more question: is it possible to shut down CAS server on the old server and reside it only on the new one? All users and old server are in the site1, and the new server is in the site2, which is physically in another country.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify all Exchange URLs and wait for Outlook clients to be automatically redirected to the new CAS server, but this is indeed possible. Be careful about available bandwidth, though...